# How to rewrite a lot of urls at once in .htacces file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am moving my CMS to Wordpress and i will redirect all my old urls using .htaccess file. 
I tried a lot of things, but it wil not work

Does anyone know how I can convert all the urls using one simple code?
(I am not moving my domain name, so the domainname will still be the same)

My old urls:

http://mywebsite.com/article_read.php/?a=7148

http://mywebsite.com/article_read.php/?a=4245

http://mywebsite.com/article_read.php/?a=7741

and so on...

My new urls:

http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?p=7148

http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?p=4245

http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?p=7741

and so on...

(Please notice the "a" in the old url, and the "p" in the new url. That makes it too difficult for me to fix it out)

Thanks,
Oktay

Comment: "Not working" isn't a useful problem description, and doesn't sound like you looked at the rewrite log.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (my original answer, it may be missing a backslash after php and an escape ?)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/article_read.php?a=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^article_read.php?a=([0-9]+)$   /wordpress/?p=$1 [L]
```

My answer edited by someone else. I'll put both here for reference

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/article_read.php\?a=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^article_read.php$   /wordpress/?p=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Matthew Page, sorry it is not working

Comment: Ok, did you try it before someone edited my answer? This is not what I wrote? Strange things going on

Comment: @MatthewPage Both versions won'r work, they contain several issues but the most important one is: you _can not_ match request arguments inside the `RewriteRule` or `%{REQUEST_URI}`. That is clearly documented and explained in the official documentation of the rewriting module. (Note: it is was not me who edited your question, but someone trying (and failing) to fix it).

Comment: @arkascha It has always worked like that for me, and it's almost the same as an example on the apache web site. But I will go back to the manuals, it's been sometime since I read them.

Comment: @mario I see why mine doesn't work now, wasn't reading the question properly. I'll give it another go later just for fun

Comment: @MatthewPage Thank you. I will wait for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should roughly be what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^|&a=(\d+)$|&
RewriteRule ^/?article_read\.php/?$ /wordpress/?p=%1 [R=301]
```

That rule should work likewise in the http servers host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). If you decide to use such a dynamic file then the interpretation of such files needs to be enabled inside the http servers host configuration and you need to place the file in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: The code you give is redirecting my urls to:

http://mysebsite.com/wordpress/

Even when i directly add the code in de Apache and Nginx config. So redirection works, but not to the right url.

@Mahtheww Page

The code you give does nothing (both of them). It does not redirect. Even not to a wrong url.

Comment: Well, `/wordpress` is the URL you asked for in the question. That is indeed where it is redirecting to. Why do you now say that is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code you give is redirecting my urls to:

http://mysebsite.com/wordpress/

Even when i directly add the code in de Apache and Nginx config. So redirection works, but not to the right url.

@Mahtheww Page

The code you give does nothing (both of them). It does not redirect. Even not to a wrong url.

Comment: This is not an answer. Edit additional info into your question.